# If $f : X \to Y$ is a rational map between affine varieties, with dense image, then does the image contain a nonempty open?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Certainly I can think of dense subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ with that lack this property - like $\mathbb{Q}^2$ (or any infinite set in $A^1$) - but they are not images of varieties. ($\mathbb{Q}^2$ has too many connected components.)

In the complex case, a similar (but different?) question would be to ask if the image of (a representative) of a dominant rational morphism always had positive measure.

Thanks!

Comment: Chevalley's theorem on constructible sets should be relevant.

Comment: Zhen Lin is right, Chevalley's theorem is stronger than above question. its proof is covered by the proof of Chevally's theorem.